# How to use Apache PDFBox to check PDF contains watermark and watermark content allows at least 6.35mm of non-printable area on each edge of a page?

Tags: pdfbox, pdfbox-layout

How to use apache pdfbox to check PDF contains watermark and watermark content allows at least 6.35mm of non-printable area on each edge of a page?

I need to support various printer margin capabilities; it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED that the watermark content allow for at least ¼” (6.35mm) of non-printable area on each edge of a page.

I want to achieve this using apache pdfbox but, not getting how to proceed.

I want to check if watermark exists in the PDF, then the watermark content allows for at least ¼” (6.35mm) of non-printable area on each edge of a page.

Comment: It may be difficult to recognize watermarks. It should be doable, though, to check whether there is _any_ content at all near to the edges.

Comment: Can be use apache pdfbox to find any embedded thumbnails within the PDF?

Comment: *"Can be use apache pdfbox to find any embedded thumbnails within the PDF?"* - see [Tilman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75614786/1729265)