# Can we use apache pdfbox to find any embedded thumbnails within the PDF?

Tags: java, pdfbox

How to use apache pdfbox to find any embedded thumbnails within the PDF. Which COSName property is used to check the same. I used CosName.Thumb but that isn't working. Any Help?

Comment: It is `COSName.THUMB`, not  `CosName.Thumb`.

Answer (score 0):

For each page, do this:

```
COSStream stream = page.getCOSObject().getCOSStream(COSName.THUMB);
if (stream != null)
{
    PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createThumbnail(stream);
}
```